# Cube effect error in Customsegue

Tags: ios, swift

I want to give my project customsegue effect on the cube. 
UIStoryboardsegue this code. However cube effect does not happen. I wonder where did I go wrong?

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class CubeSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

override func perform() {
   let source:UIViewController = self.sourceViewController as UIViewController
   let destination:UIViewController = self.destinationViewController as UIViewController

    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.type = "cube"
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
    transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)

   self.sourceViewController.navigationController!!.pushViewController(self.destinationViewController as UIViewController, animated: true)
IS}
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Where have you added the transition animation to layer ?

Comment: switch two view controller's view in a cube animation

Answer (score 0):

I need to write code in this way has ..

```
override func perform() {
    let source = self.sourceViewController as UIViewController;
    let destination = self.destinationViewController as UIViewController;

    let animation = CATransition()
    animation.type = "cube"
    animation.duration = 0.5
    animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)

        source.navigationController?.view.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: kCATransition);
        source.navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true);

}
```

}

Comment: No where in the iOS documentation, no where "cube" is defined. How is it working?